# With TypoScript, how to modify a global setting per content element

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-4.5

The background: I am using `ext:a21glossary`, but I would like to disable it's replacing of  for certain types of content elements. Actually, not for `cTypes`, but depending on what is selected via `header_layout`.

Now the question is more general: is it possible to access a general setting *per* Content element independently?

That's my basic, often-used way to use `header_layout` to wrap content elements:

```
tt_content.text.stdWrap.outerWrap.cObject=CASE
tt_content.text.stdWrap.outerWrap.cObject{
    key.field = header_layout
    default=TEXT
    default.value=<section class="clearfix" id="c{field:uid}">|</section>
    default.insertData = 1
    4=TEXT
    4.value=<section class="clearfix lit-container" id="c{field:uid}">|</section>
    4.insertData = 1
}
```

So just for daring, I tried this (`config.tx_a21glossary.noglossary=1` being the desired setting for that CE):

```
config.tx_a21glossary.noglossary.cObject = CASE
config.tx_a21glossary.noglossary.cObject {
    key.field = header_layout
    default=TEXT
    default.value= 0
    4 = TEXT
    4.value = 1
}
```

Of course, this wouldn't work.

Before I look further: is this approach (modify a global setting per CE) possible at all?

Comment: I fear this is not possible. TS works per-page and not per-content

Comment: Thanks, so that's clarified then. I've made a workaround via CSS - quick, but effectful

Comment: And specifically concerning your try: The TS property `config.tx_a21glossary.noglossary` is per [documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/a21glossary/ExtA21Glossary/Typoscript-reference/%28%28generated%29%29/Index.html) of type Boolean. You can only use `cObject` and other stdWrap-Properties on Properties that use stdWrap which Boolean does not.